# How to add element in XMLHttpRequest echoed from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

at my controller side I have three data being echoed..

```
 echo $variant->Field1;
```

and at my client side , I have the below ajax code,

```
function variants(master_id,sku)
{

                  if(master_id=="")
                  {
                     document.getElementById("variants").innerHTML = "";     
                      return false;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
                      {
                        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
                        {
                            document.getElementById("variants").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                        }

                    };
                        xhttp.open("GET", "{{ url('/getVariants') }}"+'/'+master_id+'/'+sku, true);
                        xhttp.send();
                  }
```

Now I have `

```
 <div class="column">
          <div class="ui fluid image">
          <div class="ui black ribbon label">
             <i id="variants"></i>  <!-- displaying variants -->
          </div>
             <img src="/images/wireframe/image.png">
        </div>
      </div>`
```

I dont want names to be displayed all in one  tag...instead...for every echoed data I want new column element..How should I do that?

Any answer to this is much appreciable..

Comment: What does the returned `xhttp.responseText` look like?

Comment: simple texts... i am not returning it in json encoded form

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing each data you should put all the data in an object or an array and echo a json:

```
echo json_encode($data_array);
```

From the client side then you can get the answer and iterate it to put the content in different elements.

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
{
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    var text = '';
    for(var key in jsonResponse)
    {
        text += '<p>'+jsonResponse[key]+'</p>';
    }
    document.getElementById("variants").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: but its not fixed that my variants will be three only...it can be many...so for loop here?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You can iterate with a for. I have updated the answer.